# Is there any default address to connect "aergo.io" other than "http://testnet.aergo.io:7845"?

Tags: blockchain, iot, esp32

My aim is to make blockchain-based communications between microcontrollers. I came across the security features using [aergo in github](https://github.com/aergoio/aergo-iot-microcontrollers). But when make connection to `http://testnet.aergo.io:7845` I end up with error

> Failed to connect to host (errno 113)

in esp32. Could anyone suggest me with better host address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well I have to interface aergo blockchain in microcontrollers by referring https://github.com/aergoio/aergo-iot-microcontrollers